# Form submit doesn't work in IE and Chrome

Tags: jquery, forms, dialog, submit

I've made a script to submit a form and then opens a dialog showing "added to cart". It works in FF. Chrome redirects me to the cart page and IE does nothing, not even submit anything.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var productId  = {{ product.vid }};
var addUrl = "http://shop.com/cart/add/" +productId+ "/?quantity=";

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
bakVormAsset("#formProduct");
});

function bakVormAsset(product){
jQuery(product + " #formProductQuantity").val("1");
jQuery(product + " #formProductQuantity").keyup(function () {
var val = jQuery(product + " #formProductQuantity").first().val();
});

jQuery(product + " .opener").click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
 $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(data, status) {
   var val = jQuery(product + " #formProductQuantity").first().val();

      // Go to page
      window.location.href = addUrl + val;
         $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
      return false;
 });
 }
 </script>
```

And my form looks like this:

```
 <form class="formProduct" id="formProduct" action="#" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="quantity" id="formProductQuantity" value="{{ product.stock.minimum }}" />
 <a class="button blue opener" href="" title="{{ 'Add to cart' | t }}"><span>{{ 'Add to cart' | t }}</span></a>
 </form>
```

Please help me

**EDIT**
What I forgot to mention is that off course when the form submits the user must stay on the same page and NOT being redirected to the "cart" page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

if You want to submit your form via ajax or something you have to use this plugin.

And on Complete Method you can do what ever you want to do.

```
jQuery(product + " .opener").click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
       var options = { 
           success:       function(){
                                $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
                          }  // post-submit callback 
     };

    $('#myForm2').ajaxSubmit(options); 

 });
```

You have to specify the action of the form. which action this form has to be submitted.

Comment: Is this the one and only way?

Comment: There will be so many other ways. But I prefer to do this by this pluggin. Because this plugin will handle to browser specific settings.

Comment: Ok thx.... is it possible to help me set this up in the way described above? I've read the docs from your link but it isn't that easy as you described (have limited knowledge).

Comment: Big thanks that seems to work in all browsers. I've used your code instead of mine "jQuery(product + " .opener").click(function(event) { etc...." and changed the "action" to the actual page it should submit to. Why does this work and not my code is that only because of the ajaxSubmit function?

Comment: Yes because this plugin is doing exceptionally well. all kind of browser specific settings etc and event handling. Glad to know it also works for you. :):)